# Cast parametro função Postgresql DEFAULT null::int

Tags: postgresql

Estou tentando criar uma função em plpgsql no Postgres que receba paramentros null como default.

Exemplo:

```
create or REPLACE function spinserir_0200(
p_id_entidade integer DEFAULT null::int ,
p_cod_item bigint DEFAULT NULL::bigint,
p_descr_item text DEFAULT NULL::text,
p_cod_barra bigint default NULL::BIGINT,
p_cod_ant_item integer DEFAULT NULL::integer,
p_unid_inv text DEFAULT NULL::text,
p_tipo_item text DEFAULT '00',
p_cod_ncm integer DEFAULT NULL::integer,
p_ex_ipi integer DEFAULT NULL::integer,
p_cod_gen integer DEFAULT NULL::integer,
p_cod_lst integer DEFAULT NULL::integer,
p_aliq_icms text DEFAULT NULL::text
) returns integer
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
BEGIN

INSERT INTO tb_produtos
(
ID_ENTIDADE,
COD_ITEM ,
DESCR_ITEM,
COD_BARRA,
COD_ANT_ITEM,
UNID_INV,
TIPO_ITEM,
COD_NCM,
EX_IPI,
COD_GEN,
COD_LST,
ALIQ_ICMS

)

VALUES
(
p_ID_ENTIDADE,
p_COD_ITEM,
p_DESCR_ITEM,
p_COD_BARRA,
p_COD_ANT_ITEM,
p_UNID_INV,
p_TIPO_ITEM,
p_COD_NCM,
p_EX_IPI,
p_COD_GEN,
p_COD_LST,
p_ALIQ_ICMS
);
END IF;

RETURN 1;

END ;
$$;
```

Porem mesmo eu declarando os parâmetros desta forma ele dá erro :

```
p_id_entidade integer DEFAULT null::int
```

Eu entedo que caso fosse null o parâmetro ele já faria o cast para o tipo int, porem não esta fazendo.

Ele apresenta o seguinte erro:

```
( p_id_entidade => unknown) does not exist.
```

Porem se eu passar desta forma a chamada da função:

```
 p_id_entidade:= null::int
```

Ele aceita, porem  gostaria de não precisar fazer o cast na chamada.

Existe como fazer o cast na declaração da função?

Answer (score 1):

Por padrão se vc nao colocar o "Default" ele já considerá como default null amigo... nao precisa colocar o "default null"...